# How to assign variables in VBA?

Tags: html, vba

why would this work?

```
echipe = meci2.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3 equipo ng-binding").Item(0).innerText
```

but this will raise Run-time error 438:

```
echipe = meci2.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3 equipo ng-binding")
echipa1 = echipe.Item(0).innerText
```

Comment: What data type is `meci2.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3 equipo ng-binding")`?  If it is an object, you haven't said `Set echipe = meci2.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3 equipo ng-binding")`.  And what data type is `echipe`?  (Assigning a reference to an object into a variable is different to assigning a value into a variable.)

Comment: @YowE3K it was an object and you solved my dilemma, thank you.

Comment: @YowE3K please post an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement

```
echipe = meci2.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3 equipo ng-binding").Item(0).innerText
```

it appears that you have declared `echipe` to be a `String` and that is valid syntax for assigning a value to a `String` variable. (Or perhaps you didn't declare what type `echipe` was, and therefore it has defaulted to a `Variant`, and therefore assigning a `String` value has forced it to be `Variant/String`.)

---

However, in the statement

```
echipe = meci2.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3 equipo ng-binding")
```

it appears that you have declared `echipe` to be some sort of object, or perhaps even the very generic type `Object`.  The correct syntax for assigning a reference to an object to a variable is `Set variable = object` so, in your case, you needed

```
Set echipe = meci2.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3 equipo ng-binding")
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but it's been a long time since i did this...
i could be wrong but i think this would be correct:

```
echipe = meci2.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3 equipo ng-binding").Item(0)

echipa1 = echipe.innerText
```

sorry if i'm wrong...  good luck!

Comment: Your use of `echipe.innerText` implies that `echipe` is an object, so it will still need a `Set echipe = ...`.